# How can I use substring to print delimited string

Tags: javascript, string

How can I print the first few characters of a delimited string by using substring()

```
var txt="AB:CD:EF:GH:IJ:KL:MN:OP";
document.write(txt.substring(3));
```

Comment: See this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get first 3 characters - you should use substring(0,3)

For first three "chunks":

```
txt.split(":").slice(0,3).join(":")
```

will give you "AB:CD:EF"

Comment: But I want to separate them using the delimiter. For example, first 3 should return AB:CD:EF

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the characters before the first colon, use

```
var txt="AB:CD:EF:GH:IJ:KL:MN:OP";
document.write(txt.split(":")[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks, what about returning the first 3; AB CD EF ?

Comment: Just run a loop over txt.split(":")[i] and join the results.

Answer (score 0):

`txt.substring(start, end)`

If you want the first few, starting at the beginning it would be `txt.substring(0,3);` or substitute a number for 3 wherever you want it to stop.